# Why is the file uploaded to AWS S3 0B in size?

Tags: amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-s3, nuxt.js

I am developing a webapplication with Flask as the backend and Nuxt JS as the frontend. I receive an image file from the frontend and can save it to my Flask directory structure locally. The file is ok and the images is being shown if I open it. Now i want to upload this image to AWS S3 instead of saving it to my disk. I use the boto3 SDK, here is my code:

Here is my `save_picture` method, that opens the image file and resizes it. I had the save method, but commented it out to avoid saving the file to disk as I want it only on S3.

```
def save_picture(object_id, form_picture, path):
    if form_picture is None:
        return None
    random_hex = token_hex(8)
    filename = form_picture.filename
    if '.' not in filename:
        return None
    extension = filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1].lower()
    if not allowed_file(extension, form_picture):
        return None
    picture_fn = f'{object_id}_{random_hex}.{extension}'
    picture_path = current_app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] / path / picture_fn
    # resizing image and saving the small version
    output_size = (1280, 720)
    i = Image.open(form_picture)
    i.thumbnail(output_size)
    # i.save(picture_path)
    return picture_fn
```

```
image_name = save_picture(object_id=new_object.id, form_picture=file, path=f'{object_type}_images')

s3 = boto3.client(
        's3',
        aws_access_key_id=current_app.config['AWS_ACCESS_KEY'],
        aws_secret_access_key=current_app.config['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
)

print(file)    # this prints <FileStorage: 'Capture.JPG' ('image/jpeg')>, so the file is ok

try:
    s3.upload_fileobj(
        file,
        current_app.config['AWS_BUCKET_NAME'],
        image_name,
        ExtraArgs={
            'ContentType': file.content_type
        }
    )
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return make_response({'msg': 'Something went wrong.'}, 500)
```

I can see the uploaded file in my S3, but it shows 0 B in size and if I download it, it says that it cannot be viewed.

I have tried different access policies in S3, as well as many tutorials online, nothing seems to help. Changing the version of S3 to v3 when creating the client breaks the whole system and the file is not being uploaded at all with an access error.

What could be the reason for this upload failure? I it the config of AWS or something else?
Thank you!

Comment: If you comment out `print(file)` does it make a difference? And what else are you doing with `file` in your code (we can't see any of it). How is it initialized and used elsewhere?

Comment: My suspicion is that you have consumed the content of the file object and it's now essentially at the end of the file, hence there are no more bytes to consume and your resulting S3 object is 0 bytes.

Comment: @jarmod thank you for the fast response! I added the `print(file)` afterwards, so the error was there before. I edited the question and added the function that I use to alter the file, I want to resize it and then push to S3. So your suggestion that the file is altered and this causes the error might be correct, unfortunately I cannot figure out, why my image manipulation might break the actual file... Maybe I should save the image and then open it, read the bytes and submit the read bytes to S3?

Comment: @jarmod if I avoid calling the save_picture function the file is uploaded! So you are probably correct! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @jarmod I tried to avoid the image processing and it worked. I am now resizing the image, saving it to disk, opening the saved image, not the initial file, and sending it to S3. I then delete the image on disk as I don't need it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).